# Method that checks whether two arrays have the same elements in the same order

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I'll start by saying I've been working on this problem for many hours now with no success. I've scoured the internet and nothing I've found provides an ounce of help.

The problem is quite simple:
Write a method

```
 public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] b)
```

that checks whether two arrays have the same elements in the same order.

I've had no trouble with arrays until this point, and I've begun to wonder if theres something wrong with the class as a whole.

This is my current code, one of many variations I've tried throughout the evening that all give the same result. I realize this may not be in the best syntax but it's the result of my last google search.

```
int[] a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11};
int[] b = {1, 4, 9, 16, 7, 7, 4, 9, 11};

public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] b) { 
 if (a.length != b.length)
       return false;
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       if (a[i] != b[i])
         return false;
     return true;
   }
```

As you can see, the arrays differ by only one element. The method will return false every single time, whether they are equal or not. I've used

```
Arrays.equals(a,b);
```

and

```
Arrays.equals(a[i], b[i]);
```

Returns false every time. I'm using Dr. Java and the interactions panel allows you to enter just about any expression. Multiple times I have declared both arrays in the interactions panel, and then compared them using the first method above, and it returns true.

I'm at a complete loss at this point. Any help is appreciated and I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I feel like my case is unique.

Edit:

```
System.out.println( "equals(): " + equals(a, b)  );
```

Is the call to the equals method.

Edit #2:

Here is the entire code for the class, it's a pre made homework template which is why I avoided posting the entire thing.

The method in question is P6.9

import java.util.Arrays;

```
class Homework5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 int[] a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11};
 int[] b = {1, 4, 9, 16, 7, 7, 4, 9, 11};

 //P6.6
 System.out.println( "P66(): " + P66(a) ); // should print: P68(): -2 

 //P6.7
 System.out.println( "P67(): " + prettyPrint( P67(a) ) );   //should print: P67(): [11, 9, 4, 7,      9, 16, 9, 4, 1] 

 //P6.9
 System.out.println( "equals(): " + equals(a, b)  ); // should print: P69(): false 

 //P6.10
 System.out.println( "sameSet(): " +  sameSet(a, b)  ); // should print:  P610(): true 

}

//this method can be used to see a nice visual representation of an array of ints
public static String prettyPrint(int[] array) {
 if (array == null) {
 return "null"; 
 }
 String answer = "[";
 for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
 answer += array[i] + ", ";
 }
 answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length() -2);
 answer += "]";
 return answer; 
 }


//***************************
//*****  Problem P6.6  ******
//***************************

//Problem P6.6
public static int P66(int[] array) {
  int sum = array[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < (array.length - 1); i++) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      sum -= array[i + 1];
    }
    else {
      sum += array[i + 1];
    }
  }
 return sum;
 }

//***************************
//*****  Problem P6.7  ******
//***************************

//Problem P6.7
public static int[] P67(int[] array) {
  if ((array.length % 2) == 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= ((array.length / 2 ) - 1); i++) {
   int a = array[i];
   int b = array[array.length - (i + 1)];
   array[i] = b;
   array[array.length - (i + 1)] = a;
  }
  }
  else {
   for (int i = 0; i <= (array.length / 2 ); i++) {
   int a = array[i];
   int b = array[array.length - (i + 1)];
   array[i] = b;
   array[array.length - (i + 1)] = a;
  }
  }
 return array;
 }

//***************************
//*****  Problem P6.9  ******
//***************************

//Problem P6.9
public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] b) { 
  if (a.length != b.length)
       return false;
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       if (a[i] != b[i])
         return false;
     return true;
   }

//***************************
//*****  Problem P6.10  *****
//***************************

//Problem P6.10
public static boolean sameSet(int[] a, int[] b) {
return false;
}

}
```

Comment: `Multiple times I have declared both arrays in the interactions panel, and then compared them using the first method above, and it returns true` expand it

Comment: Run the program in the debugger and step through the loop by hand. Figure out at which point the `if` statement is evaluating to `true` and returning `false`. Also, if you're declaring the arrays in the interactions panel and then re-running the code, the code is still using the values in the declarations, not whatever you might have typed in the IDE interface.

Comment: I removed the method from the class and placed it in its own class. I copied the arrays and code to the new class. Set the arrays to be equal, ran the code and it produced true. The problem has to lie in the class itself then correct?

Comment: How are you calling your equals method? Post that code as well.

Comment: The only time it fails to work is when the class itself runs. If the method is in it's own class, it produces the correct answer. The only problem is I have no clue what would cause it to fail other than calling the incorrect array?

Comment: What do you mean "when the class itself runs"?  Can you post the entire class, for the case when it fails?  Because, as you've already said, the method itself works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `P67` is modifying the array that you're passing to it.  So you don't have the original values in array `a` when you call `equals`.  Remove the line that says

```
System.out.println( "P67(): " + prettyPrint( P67(a) ) );
```

Comment: Awesome, commenting out the line fixed the issue. My only question now is how do I get it to work with the line included? The class has to print all four answers to receive credit.

Comment: Do you have to call those four methods in the correct order?  Maybe you can do `equals` first and `P67` later?  Alternatively, you could just make a copy of array `a`.

Comment: I'd rather not switch the order because I don't believe it is graded by a human. To my knowledge each method is ran through a few test cases to check correctness. By making a copy do you mean make a copy of "a" within P6.7 and use it?

Comment: Yes, you could make the copy within `P67`, so that it doesn't modify its input - I'm not sure whether that fits the spec of what `P67` is supposed to do.  Alternatively, you could make the copy within `main`, and just pass one copy to `P67` and the other copy to `equals`.

Comment: I'll have to check with a professor on that one to see what is preferred. Thanks for the help! I'm glad to know the problem isn't with my method.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, because when I run the code in Intelli IDEA - it works.  False for the base case.  When I change the 7 to a 9 to get a match, I get true.   If I remove an element - I get false back.

I agree the formatting could be improved but for me, the code works, unless I am missing something in the question.

Here's the code in my IDE, with a couple minor changes:

```
package util;

/**
 * Created by mike on 2/19/14.
 */
public class SOArrays {

public static int[] a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11};
public static int[] b = {1, 4, 9, 16, 7, 4, 9, 11};
//public static int[] b = {1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11};
//public static int[] b = {1, 4, 9, 16, 7, 7, 4, 9, 11};

public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length != b.length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("equals: "+SOArrays.equals(a, b));
}
}
```

And this worked.

Comment: Not really an answer.  The OP wants to know why his/her code doesn't work.  This just says "I don't know".

Comment: When I remove the method from the class and run it separately I get it to produce the correct answer as well. That leads me to believe the method is calling the incorrect arrays. The only issue is that they are the only arrays in the class.

Comment: @DavidWallace What I said was - the code is working - at least for me it worked.

Comment: in other words, you don't know why it didn't work when the OP ran it.  I also don't know why it didn't work when the OP ran it, which is why I haven't posted an answer yet.

Comment: Okay - I can see your point.  I will put my 'version' in the response.

Comment: Seriously, don't bother doing that.  Unless you're quite sure that you know why this doesn't work for the OP.